# Trying to access array offset on value of type int for one of the objects but the others are working fine, the isset is TRUE. need to understand why

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, php-8.2

Inside the loop the $qty[$key] and  $action[$key] both works fine but I am facing this error with the $batch_id[$key]. The loop I used for test is just two indexes. and the dd of $data as shown below. I also noticed that the quantity gets updated for the first index only in the database, which means the issue is with the second index as it does not get updated.

I can't figure how come its not working only with the batch_id, anyone have an idea?

I tried to essign the $batch_id[$key] to a var and use this var but not that is not working too. and the dd(isset($batch_id[$key])); is true for both index[0] and index[1]

```
array:12 [▼ // app/Http/Controllers/AdjustmentController.php:201
       "_token" => "TWFJuqmjro2Jdhovo28vAw0pjePLfEHp2bI0gcm1"
       "warehouse_id" => "2"
       "stock_count_id" => "46"
       "qty" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "1"
        1 => "3"
       ]
      "action" => array:2 [▼
       0 => "+"
       1 => "-"
      ]
      "product_id" => array:2 [▼
       0 => "114"
       1 => "114"
      ]
      "product_code" => array:2 [▼
       0 => "36089125"
       1 => "36089125"
      ]
      "batch_id" => array:2 [▼
       0 => "761"
       1 => "762"
      ]
      "total_qty" => "4"
      "item" => "2"
      "note" => null
      "reference_no" => "adr-20231210-082622"
     ]
```

```
@foreach($names as $key=>$name)
 <tr>
   <td>{{$name}}</td>
   <td>{{$code[$key]}}</td>
   <td>{{$batch_id[$key]}}</td>
   <td><input type="number" class="form-control qty" name="qty[]" value="{{$qty[$key]}}" required step="any" /></td>
   <td class="action">                                                                 <select name="action[]" class="form-control act-val">                                                                       @if($action[$key] == '+')                                                                                <option value="+">{{trans("file.Addition")}}</option>                                                                          <option value="-">{{trans("file.Subtraction")}}</option>                                                                       @else                                                                             <option value="-">{{trans("file.Subtraction")}}</option>                                                                              <option value="+">{{trans("file.Addition")}}</option>                                                                          @endif
    </select>
   </td>
   <td>                                                                     <button type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger">{{trans("file.delete")}}</button>
     <input type="hidden" class="product-id" name="product_id[]" value="{{$product_id[$key]}}" />                                                              <input type="hidden" class="product-code" name="product_code[]" value="{{$code[$key]}}" />
     <input type="hidden" class="batch_id" name="batch_id[]" value="{{$batch_id[$key]}}"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforeach


public function store(Request $request)
     {
        $data = $request->except('document');
        $product_id = $data['product_id'];
        $product_code = $data['product_code'];
        $batch_id= $data['batch_id'];
        $qty = $data['qty'];
        $action = $data['action'];
        foreach ($product_id as $key => $pro_id) {
            $lims_product_data = Product::find($pro_id);
            $myBatch=$batch_id[$key] ;
                $lims_product_warehouse_data = Product_Warehouse::where([
                    ['product_id', $pro_id],
                    ['product_batch_id', $myBatch],
                    ['warehouse_id', $data['warehouse_id'] ],
                ])->first();
                $lims_product_batch_data = ProductBatch::select('id', 'batch_no', 'qty', 'expired_date')->where('id',$myBatch)->first();
                if($action[$key] == '-'){
                    $lims_product_batch_data->qty -= $qty[$key];
                    $lims_product_data->qty -= $qty[$key];
                    $lims_product_warehouse_data->qty -= $qty[$key];
                }
                elseif($action[$key] == '+'){
                    $lims_product_batch_data->qty += $qty[$key];
                    $lims_product_data->qty += $qty[$key];
                    $lims_product_warehouse_data->qty += $qty[$key];
                }
                $lims_product_batch_data->save();
                $lims_product_data->save();
                $lims_product_warehouse_data->save();
                $batch_id = $lims_product_batch_data->id;

        }
        return redirect('qty_adjustment')->with('message', 'Data inserted successfully');
    }
```

Comment: what is the error line?

Comment: this one:   $myBatch=$batch_id[$key] ;

$myBatch is the value I'm using in the lims_product_warehouse_data where statement

Comment: what is the value of `var_dump($batch_id);`?

Comment: array (2) { [0]=> string(3) "761" [1]=> string(3) "762" }

Comment: so now I figured it out, I converted it to $batch_id = array_map('intval', $batch_id); but I am facing an issue with the logic as both operation the "+ and -" are performed on the first batch, where the first operation should be performed on the first batch and the second operation should be performed on the second batch and so on fore more batches

Comment: according to your data set, you are looping over an array of the same product ids "114" so it make sense that you are performing the both actions on the same product

Comment: the two indexes will have the same product id, but shouldn't they get a different batch if based on this line $myBatch=$batch_id[$key] ;?

 which is still having the same error sorry I thought I solved it but I am still facing the same error. I have been trying for hours and I guess my brain is not functioning well right now... I will appreciate your help if possible. the var_dump($batch_id); is array (2) { [0]=> int "761" [1]=> int "762" } but the same error with the same line

Comment: You must add some debugging checks to debug your code, before this line `$myBatch=$batch_id[$key] ;` add a condition to give you more insights about the actual value of this variable, for example something like `if (!isset($batch_id[$key])) { dd($batch_id, $key); }` of-course using more advanced debugging tools like xDebug will help you in such a scenarios

Comment: it returns the same array (2) { [0]=> int(761) [1]=> int(762) }

Comment: what is the `$key` value?

Comment: the dd does not mention it. it only shows the batch_id values. should I change the loop condition itself?

Comment: I modified the code to show the front_end of it which passes the values and the table actually shows the "761, 762" in the batch column

Comment: I mean `dd($batch_id, $key);` what is it's output?

Comment: The condition of the if (!isset($batch_id[$key])) is not met.

Comment: how does the condition is not met and the code keep throwing the error? do you mean that the error is coming from the front-end?

Comment: foreach ($product_id as $key => $pro_id) {
            $lims_product_data = Product::find($pro_id);
            if (!isset($batch_id[$key])) { dd($batch_id, $key); }
            $myBatch=$batch_id[$key];
                $lims_product_warehouse_data = Product_Warehouse::where([
                    ['product_id', $pro_id],
                    ['product_batch_id', $batch_id[$key]],
                    ['warehouse_id', $data['warehouse_id'] ],
                ])->first();
         }
if we just wrote this, there is no error. so maybe the key itself

Comment: this is not a valid case, if the variable is not set and giving you an error it must apply the if condition, most likely the error is coming from another place `<td>{{$batch_id[$key]}}</td>` for example

Comment: I had this line $batch_id = $lims_product_batch_data->id; before the return line which I ignored in my question thinking the error is from the  $myBatch=$batch_id[$key] ;  as this was the line highlighted in the error page but I commented all line and walked step by step with uncommenting and dd till the error showed when I uncommented this line

Comment: Please post all relevant details in the question body as an [edit] then delete your redundant comments. Please post your data from `var_export()` instead of `dd()`.